# Показать блоки друг за другом

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2300) {
    $('.first').addClass("fadeInLeft");
    setTimeout(function() {
             $('.second').addClass("fadeInDown");
         }, 300);
     setTimeout(function() {
         $('.third').addClass("fadeInRight");
         }, 600);
}
```

Вот так я на данный момент показываю блоки. Но хотелось бы при добавлении блока не переписывать скрипт. Попытался сделать так, показывает только первый блок:

```
var iter=0;
var a=$('.price-col');
var b=a.length;
var timerId=setTimeout( function fadin() {
   if (iter!=b){
      a.eq(iter).addClass('fadeInDown');
      timerId=setTimeout(fadin,100);}
            },300);
```

Подскажите как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно завернуть такую пошаговую анимацию в рекурсию:

```js
function animateList(list, animation, time) {
  return new Promise(function(ok) {
    step();
    function step() {
      if (!list.length) return ok();
      animation(list.shift());
      setTimeout(step, time);
    }
  });
}

var list = [...document.querySelectorAll('.square')];
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){

  animateList(list.slice(), function(el){
    el.classList.add('green-bg');
  }, 100)
   .then(function(){
     list.forEach(function(el){el.classList.remove('green-bg')})
   });
})
```

```css
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.green-bg {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">1</div>
<div class="square">2</div>
<div class="square">3</div>
<div class="square">4</div>
<div class="square">5</div>
<div class="square">6</div>
<div class="square">7</div>
<div class="square">8</div>
<hr/>
<button>Animate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

переменная `iter` не меняет значение.
вместо `if` попробуйте использовать `while` и менять переменную `iter++;`

```
var timerId=setTimeout( function fadin() {
 while (iter!=b){
  a.eq(iter).addClass('fadeInDown');
  timerId=setTimeout(fadin,100);
   iter++;
  }
 },300);
```